# If files would be linked symmetrically, what should be the result for editing et the same time?

Tags: python, logic

If I have a python script like this:

```py
import threading

def link(a,b):
    while True:
        with open(a) as f:
            content = f.read()
        if content:
            print (content)
            with open(b, "w") as f:
                f.write(content)


t = threading.Thread(target=link, args=("x", "y")).start()
s = threading.Thread(target=link, args=("y", "x")).start()
```

And when I let it run and start editing the files x and y, I get some random results, what is in these files. Sometimes they get some newlines, sometimes one gets empty. Where this comes from? I would suggest, there is sometimes the content I wrote into this file sometimes not. But not something else. The thought behind this is, what would happen, if we link all our shell histories. What should be the content of the file, if people execute commands "at the same time". They would have different histories because of time, but the linking of the files should make them the same. But both are right themselves from their point of time, if "a" was executed before "b" came, that came in as new line of the history, and vice versa.

```
% cat y
hello
% echo "hello world" > x
% cat y                 
hello
% echo "hello world! how are you?" > x
% cat y                               
hello
% cat x
hello
% echo "hello world! how are you doing?" > x
% cat x                                     
hello
% cat y
hello
% echo "hello world! how are you?" > x     
% cat y                                
hello
world! how are you?
% echo "hello world! how are you?" > x 
% 
% cat y                               
hello
world! how are you?
% cat y
hello
world! how are you?
% echo "hello world! how are you?" > x
% cat y                               
hello
world! how are you?
% echo "hello world! how are you?" > x
% cat y                               
hello
world! how are you?
% echo "hello world! how are you?" > x
% cat y                               
% echo "hello world! how are you?" > x
% cat y                               
hello
world! how are you?
```

Comment: Maybe read about race conditions

Comment: You need to use some kind of locking to prevent multiple threads from writing the file at the same time.

Comment: Oh, I'm executing this on MacOS and it does not have file locking by the OS. https://apple.slashdot.org/story/03/02/21/0919220/open-file-locking-and-mac-os-x

Comment: In case of a race condition I would not expect to find newlines or emptiness in that file, but a kind of mixture of both versions in both files, as it looks sometimes like.